# Is it possible in Android to keep app in background alive

Tags: android, xamarin

There is a Xamarin app that I didn't develop and I don't have the source code for.
It's important that android OS will not kill or put this app to sleep if the user didn't use it for a 2-3 hours.
Can I develop another small app or service that will help keeping this app alive?
I already red online articles and tried changing battery optimization settings. Nothing worked.

Answer (score 0):

there are no methods in API for manipulating other apps lifecycle, system decides when it is needed to kill some app. maybe you can introduce some own custom `AccessibilityService`, which will start this target app foreground (simplest way: open launcher `Activity`, just start app as usual):

```
Intent intent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("target.app.package");
startActivity(intent);
```

and then after few seconds "home" it using below

```
Intent homeIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

note that this operation will be visible for user